# How can I reproduce this gradient effect?

Tags: gradient

I don't understand how to make these blurry shapes. Should I use PS or AI? Thanks in advance

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Better use photoshop since there’s blur involved in it.

In Photoshop Filters, there’s an effect in Render > Lighting

You can customise the lighting and colorise it later using Levels, curves HSV adjustments etc.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Illustrator for work like this. Blurs and gradients are much better in raster software such as Photoshop. Paint some splodge shapes using a soft edged blur, then apply some a Gaussian blur.

[image][image]

Add noise (zoom shown is 100%)

[image]